# Substitute json value with space using sed and regex

Tags: json, regex, sed

I have multiple json file, which look like the sample below:

```
#sample json    
{"urlCurrent":"https://www.website1.com/inside/377/388/408/8002.html?utm_source=source&utm_medium=Click&utm_campaign=123","id":"00001"}
{"urlCurrent":"https://127.0.0.1/inside/414/756/765/34984.html","id":"00002"}
{"urlCurrent":"https://msdn.anything.com/en-us","id":"00002"}
{"urlCurrent":"https://web.something.com/","id":"00002"}
```

I would like the json to become:

```
#result json    
{"urlCurrent":"https://www.website1.com/","id":"00001"}
{"urlCurrent":"https://127.0.0.1/","id":"00002"}
{"urlCurrent":"https://msdn.anything.com/","id":"00002"}
{"urlCurrent":"https://web.something.com/","id":"00002"}
```

I think that with

```
sed -i 's/{regular expression}/\ /g' sample.json
```

which is to substitute anything after / with space, the result can be achieved. However, I don't know how to use regular expression to match the pattern I need. Neither do I know which keyword I should search in order to achieve this.

Is there a way to truncate the urlCurrent to become the result I need?
Thanks in advance!

---

12/23 Update
This works:

```
sed -E -i -r 's!(http|ftp|https)://([0-9a-zA-Z\.]+)([0-9a-zA-Z\/\.?#=_&%~+-]+)!\2!g' sample.json
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -i -r 's/(.*:\/\/?[^\/]+\/?)[^\"]*(.*)/\1\2/' sample.json
```

Comment: sed: 1: "s/(.*:\/\/?[^\/]+\/?)[^ ...": \1 not defined in the RE

Comment: Thanks for the reply! However, it didn't work on my end.
I am still working on it, and will edited my question once I figure it out.

Comment: What about this one (depends on the _sed_ implementation): `sed -i -E 's/(.*:\/\/?[^\/\"]+\/?)[^\"]*(.*)/\1\2/' sample.json`

Comment: Still doesn't work. The same message show up. I have updated my question. Thanks for your help!